# Tor security if ISP blocks TLS channel?

Tags: tls, tor

If ISP blocks TLS channel while a user is using Tor, can he read the Tor traffic, since Tor uses TLS encryption ?

Answer (score 4):

Tor will simply not work without encryption. When the ISP blocks the connection to the Tor network, Tor will not attempt to create an unencrypted connection as a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Blocking a channel simply means that communication cannot take place along that channel.  In order to read the content of a TLS channel, the attacker (in this case, the ISP) would need copies of the secret keys involved.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, Tor encryption works by encrypting your data with the public key of a randomly chosen node, doing the same for the result and repeating that again so everything is encrypted three times. Information on where to sent the data is included before applying each layer of encryption. The resulting data will be sent to the node that owns the private key for the last "layer".

If the data is blocked, this simply means that node won't get your packet and the connection fails. Since everything is encrypted, this cannot be used to unmask you.

Additionally, if your ISP is blocking TLS it may still be possible to connect to the Tor network.

There are various anti-blocking measures included with Tor called [pluggable transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en) which can be used to bypass a block. The *Flashproxy* pluggable transport uses unencrypted web sockets to send the encrypted data (so it is sending chunks of encrypted data over an unencrypted channel) and will most likely still work if your ISP blocks all TLS connections.